# Analyzing a partially crossed design

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I have a data set from a test (*see below*). The scoring algorithm gives each item (`item_id`) a score (`y`) that is continuous from $0$ to $1$ (exactly like probabilities, the higher the more correct). The problem is that the item pool is very huge for test security reasons, so that items are not exposed much.

As a result, only a handful of the exact same items are assigned to $\ge 100$ test takers (`person_id`), hence this is a **partially crossed design**. In this data set, there are $16004$ unique `item_id`s but there are only $2000$ test takers. Only $11$ items have been employed more than $100$ times, and $5$ over $200$ times, and $4$ over $300$ times.

I wonder what modeling framework can tell me the item difficulty of each item, in the [IRT Rasch model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasch_model#The_mathematical_form_of_the_Rasch_model_for_dichotomous_data) sense of the word, on this test?

I would highly appreciate an `R` demonstration.

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilzl/i/master/d.csv')

tab <- table(dat$item_id)
sapply(1:3*1e2, function(i) length(tab[tab >= i])) # items nested within 100-300 'person_id's
# > [1] 11  5  4
```

Comment: Does a higher score on y mean that the score is more 'correct'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are describing a **partially crossed** design.  The good news is that this is one of Doug Bates's main development goals for `lme4`: efficiently fitting large, partially crossed linear mixed models.  **Disclaimer**: I don't know that much about Rasch models nor how close a partially nested model like this gets to it: from a brief glance at [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v020i02), it seems that it's pretty close.

Some general data checking and exploration:

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilzl/i/master/d.csv')
plot(tt_item <- table(dat$item_id))
plot(tt_person <- table(dat$person_id))
table(tt_person)
tt <- with(dat,table(item_id,person_id))
table(tt)
```

Confirming that (1) items have highly variable counts; (2) persons have 21-32 counts; (3) person:item combinations are never repeated.

Examining the crossing structure:

```
library(lme4)
## run lmer without fitting (optimizer=NULL)
form <- y ~ item_type + (1| item_id) + (1 | person_id)
f0 <-  lmer(form,
              data = dat,
        control=lmerControl(optimizer=NULL))
```

View the random effects model matrix:

```
image(getME(f0,"Zt"))
```

[image]

The lower diagonal line represents the indicator variable for persons: the upper stuff is for items.  The fairly uniform fill confirms that there's no particular pattern to the combination of items with persons.

Re-do the model, this time actually fitting:

```
system.time(f1 <- update(f0, control=lmerControl(), verbose=TRUE))
```

This takes about 140 seconds on my (medium-powered) laptop.  Check diagnostic plots:

```
plot(f1,pch=".", type=c("p","smooth"), col.line="red")
```

[image]

And the scale-location plot:

```
 plot(f1,sqrt(abs(resid(.)))~fitted(.),
     pch=".", type=c("p","smooth"), col.line="red")
```

[image]

So there do appear to be some problems with nonlinearity and heteroscedasticity here.

If you want to fit the (0,1) values in a more appropriate way (and maybe deal with the nonlinearity and heteroscedasticity problems), you can try a mixed Beta regression:

```
library(glmmTMB)
system.time(f2 <-  glmmTMB(form,
              data = dat,
              family=beta_family()))
```

This is slower (~1000 seconds).

Diagnostics (I'm jumping through a few hoops here to deal with some slowness in `glmmTMB`'s `residuals()` function.)

```
system.time(f2_fitted <- predict(f2, type="response", se.fit=FALSE))
v <- family(f2)$variance
resid <- (f2_fitted-dat$y)/sqrt(v(f2_fitted))  ## Pearson residuals
f2_diag <- data.frame(fitted=f2_fitted, resid)
g1 <- mgcv::gam(resid ~ s(fitted, bs ="cs"), data=f2_diag)
xvec <- seq(0,1, length.out=201)
plot(resid~fitted, pch=".", data=f2_diag)
lines(xvec, predict(g1,newdata=data.frame(fitted=xvec)), col=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Scale-location plot:

```
g2 <- mgcv::gam(sqrt(abs(resid)) ~ s(fitted, bs ="cs"), data=f2_diag)
plot(sqrt(abs(resid))~fitted, pch=".", data=f2_diag)
lines(xvec, predict(g2,newdata=data.frame(fitted=xvec)), col=2,lwd=2)
```

[image]

A few more questions/comments:

- the `ranef()` method will retrieve the random effects, which represent the relative difficulties of items (and the relative skill of persons)
- you might want to worry about the remaining nonlinearity and heteroscedasticity, but I don't immediately see easy options (suggestions from commenters welcome)
- adding other covariates (e.g. gender) might help the patterns or change the results ...
- this is not the 'maximal' model (see Barr et al 2013: i.e., since each individual gets multiple item types, you probably want a term of the form `(item_type|person_id)` in the model - however, beware that these fits will take even longer ...

Comment: what plot do you get instead/how does it differ?

Comment: I actually used `pdf("tmp.pdf",width=12,height=4); image(...); dev.off()`.  It could well be that if your plot area is too small, the individual cells are <1 pixel wide and hence disappear.

Comment: for what it's worth the 'maximal' model has been running for nearly 2 hours and I'm guessing it's less than halfway there ...

Comment: `f2` is a Beta model, so it does have a link function - it's a logit link by default

Comment: Great answer Ben! In the spirit of OP's question, would you mind demonstrating the extraction of the difficulties of items and the relative skill of persons from this particular model? It would be very helpful for those following this post closely. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: It's really not much more complicated than `ranef(f2)` (which returns a list with a data frame for each random effect), but I will when I get a chance.  Constructing caterpillar plots is a little bit trickier/less automatic with glmmTMB than with lme4 models

Comment: `ranef()` gives the deviations of each group from the population mean/fixed-effects expectation. `coef()` gives the estimated value for each group (i.e., including fixed effects)

Comment: Sure, I would certainly want to avoid making a mistake while combining fixed and random effects to obtain the item diff. and person skills, so it would be wonderful if you could demonstrate that, thank you:-)

Comment: I gave up on it after 4 or 5 hours.  I may try it again on my desktop at work (which I can reach remotely), or I may try running it in Doug Bates's Julia package ...

Comment: Sure, me too I gave up on it after 5 hours. I also see some comments about item and person estimates extraction, if you could add those that would be great :0) Once again, thank you for your expertise!

Comment: Ben, when we say the design is partially crossed, we also mean that the design is partially nested, right? If not, how did you determine that OP's design is specifically partially crossed?

Comment: Dear Ben, I was wondering if you could possibly comment on [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/635312/284623)?