# What it means to model the residuals of a multilevel model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have a highly skewed dataset. But, my MODEL of choice below shows drastically improved, normally distributed residuals (and predicted values) compared to other models whose residuals are not modeled.

Two questions:

1- Is MODEL below assuming that my data for each `subject` come from **normal populations** whose variances are unequal across levels of `X1_categorical` as well as being also a power function of `X2_numeric` variables?

2- Does the distribution of residuals (*below*) tell us anything about the distribution of any part of data (ex. data for each `subject`, or the marginal distribution across all subjects etc.)

```
hist(resid(MODEL, type = "normalized"))
```

```
 MODEL <- nlme::lme(y ~ X1_categorical + X2_numeric,
         random = ~1| subject,
         data = data,
         correlation = corSymm(~1|subject),
         weights = varComb(varIdent(form = ~ 1 |  X1_categorical ),
                                          varPower(form = ~  X2_numeric )))
```

Answer (score 5):

From the `correlation` and `weights` arguments in the column it appears that you have specified a fully unstructured variance covariance matrix.  This is often a good choice since it imposes no *a priori* structure and let's the data do the talking.

I think the first of your questions is correct, but I'm not sure what you are getting at in your second question.

Comment: From `?nlme::varPower`, " the power variance function is defined as s2(v) =|v|^(2*t), where t is the variance function coefficient", i.e. the *standard deviation* increases as a power of `t` of the specified covariate

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you. [`corSymm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/corSymm.html) is the *unstructured* representation of Level 1 residuals not a compound symmetric one. Also, can you please connect my 2nd question to your answer when you say: *"A histogram of residuals may indicate that they are plausibly normally distributed"*?

Comment: Doh, I should really read the documentation before answering sometimes ! You are right, it's not compound symmetric. I will amend my answer a bit later.

Comment: To be honest, I think my first question (the correct one) is also not fully answered. I already know what `corSymm` does, my first question was about the `weights=` part and the way it envisions the data generating process? My 2nd question (the incorrect one) has to do with the fact that in a linear model each data point on the response variable (y_ij) is modeled as an additive function of a predicted value and sum of the distances of that predicted value has from y_ij. I thought that under normality of response for each subject, or across all subjects, the level-1 residual is a reflection...

Comment: ... of the distribution of y_ij.

Comment: @BenBolker, Ben is the model I sketched in my question essentially a location-scale model?